# Calibrated boosted decision trees in R or MATLAB

Tags: r, classification, matlab

In [An Empirical Comparison of Supervised Learning Algorithms](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~caruana/ctp/ct.papers/caruana.icml06.pdf) (ICML 2006) the authors (Rich Caruana and Alexandru Niculescu-Mizil) evaluated several classification algorithms (SVMs, ANN, KNN, Random Forests, Decision Trees, etc.), and reported that calibrated boosted trees ranked as the best learning algorithm overall across eight different metrics (F-score, ROC Area, average precision, cross-entropy, etc.).

I would like to test **calibrated boosted decision trees** in one of my projects, and was wondering if anybody could suggest a good R package or MATLAB library for this.

I am relatively new to R, although I have large experience with MATLAB and Python. I have read about R's **gbm**, **tree**, and **rpart** but I am not sure if these packages  implement calibrated boosted decision trees or if there are others that implement them.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

About R, I would vote for the [gbm](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gbm/index.html) package; there's a vignette that provides a good overview: [Generalized Boosted Models: A guide to the gbm package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gbm/vignettes/gbm.pdf). If you are looking for an unified interface to ML algorithms, I recommend the [caret](http://caret.r-forge.r-project.org/Classification_and_Regression_Training.html) package which has built-in facilities for data preprocessing, resampling, and comparative assessment of model performance. Other packages for boosted trees are reported under Table 1 of one of its accompanying vignettes, [Model tuning, prediction and performance functions](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/vignettes/caretTrain.pdf). There is also an example of parameters tuning for boosted trees in the [JSS paper](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v28/i05/paper), pp. 10-11.

**Note:** I didn't check, but you can also look into [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) (there's an R interface, [RWeka](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RWeka/index.html)).

Comment: Thanks @chl. I'll take a look at them. Do you know if any of these packages provide calibrated outputs? (i.e. calibrated probabilities, rather than just scores)

Comment: I understood the question to be:"Have platt scaling or Isotonic regression methods been implemented in R?"

Comment: @user023472 Did you ever find an answer to this issue?